# No overload for method `FeedShare' takes `6' arguments Facebook SDK v7.1.0 Unity

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game with Facebook share but i keep getting this error:

No overload for method `FeedShare' takes`6' arguments

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;

public class FBHolder : MonoBehaviour {

void Awake ()
{
        FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);

}

private void SetInit ()
{
    Debug.Log ("Facebook Init done");

    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        Debug.Log ("Facebook logged in");
    } else {
        FBLogin();
    }
}

private void OnHideUnity (bool isGameShown)
{
    if (!isGameShown) {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    } else {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}

void FBLogin()
{
    var perms = new List<string> (){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (perms, AuthCallback);
}

private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) {
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        Debug.Log("FB Login Worked");
        // share facebook
        FB.FeedShare(
            link: "https://enterlinkhere.com",
            linkName: "PollyCube",
            linkCaption: "LinkCaption",
            linkDescription: "LinkDescription",
            picture: "https://enterimagehere.com",
            callback: LogCallback
            );

    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}



void LogCallback(IResult response) {
    Debug.Log("Worked");
}


}
```

and this is the code for the Facebook Feedshare (also in the code i posted above)

```
            FB.FeedShare(
            link: "https://enterlinkhere.com",
            linkName: "PollyCube",
            linkCaption: "LinkCaption",
            linkDescription: "LinkDescription",
            picture: "https://enterimagehere.com",
            callback: LogCallback
            );

    void LogCallback(IResult response) {
    Debug.Log("Worked");
}
```

I am using this documentation to make this in case you are wondering where i got this from

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.FeedShare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FB.FeedShare(
        string.Empty, //toId
        new System.Uri("https://enterlinkhere.com"), //link
        "PollyCube", //linkName
        "LinkCaption", //linkCaption
        "LinkDescription", //linkDescription
        new System.Uri("https://enterimagehere.com"), //picture
        string.Empty, //mediaSource
        LogCallback //callback
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the toID field - even though they say "You don't need to specify toID to post to the current user's timeline - just leave it empty.
", that doesn't mean you can not put in the parameter!

Try putting in "" or string.Empty instead...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing link and picture by this

new System.Uri("https://enterlinkhere.com"),